# Pattern Searching in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames as below.  DF1 is slighly messy (as you can see below) has multiple values from DF2 combined into one column.

```
DF1
SRNo.      Value
1      1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL
2      1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL/7MLPO0OKMN8MNBV
3      3ABCD4EFGH5IJKL
4      3ABCD4EFGH5IJKL/1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL
5      7MLPO0OKMN8MNBV/9IUYT7HGFD3LKJH
```

```
DF2
SRNo.   Value
1   1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL
2   3ABCD4EFGH5IJKL
3   6PQRS7TUVW8XYZA
4   5FGHI9XUZX1RATP
5   9AGTY6UGFW0AAUU
6   6TEYD7RARA8MHAT
7   9IUYT7HGFD3LKJH
```

I want to do a look up using values column in both the data set.  Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

i) For rows 1 & 3 in DF1 it is a simple look up in DF2.  I expect the code to return those looked up values. 
ii) For row #3 in DF1,  only first part of the string matches with a value in DF2.  I expect the code to return only the first part. 
iii) For row#4 in DF1,  both the parts in the string matches with values in DF2.  In this case I want the first part of the string that is matching to be retained 
iv) For Row #5,  the second part in the string matches with the value in DF2.  I would expect the code to return the 2nd part of the string.

I have around 47000 rows in first dataset and over 300,000 in second dataset and ofcourse there are other columns in both the datasets.  I have tried this in multiple ways using str_split/str_match but could not accomplish what I want to.  Every suggestion is appreciated.  My rest of the coding is in R.

Thank You

Comment: Please add the **desired outcome** to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to `tidyr::separate()` your DF1 at "/". Then I used `dplyr::case_when()` to see if there was a match between the first of the listed items in DF2 with `%in%`; if there wasn't then check against the second. I used `dplyr::mutate()` to append the results to DF1 under `dat`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF1 <- data.frame("SRNo." = 1:5, Value = c("1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL","1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL/7MLPO0OKMN8MNBV","3ABCD4EFGH5IJKL","3ABCD4EFGH5IJKL/1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL","7MLPO0OKMN8MNBV/9IUYT7HGFD3LKJH"), stringsAsFactors = F) %>% tbl_df()

DF2 <- data.frame("SRNo." = 1:7, Value = c("1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL","3ABCD4EFGH5IJKL","6PQRS7TUVW8XYZA","5FGHI9XUZX1RATP","9AGTY6UGFW0AAUU","6TEYD7RARA8MHAT","9IUYT7HGFD3LKJH"), stringsAsFactors = F) %>%tbl_df()

DF1 %>%
  separate(Value, c("Value1", "Value2"), sep = "/")  %>%
  mutate(dat = case_when(
    Value1 %in% DF2$Value ~ Value1,
    Value2 %in% DF2$Value ~ Value2,
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  ))

# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#   SRNo. Value1          Value2          dat            
#   <int> <chr>           <chr>           <chr>          
# 1     1 1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL NA              1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL
# 2     2 1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL 7MLPO0OKMN8MNBV 1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL
# 3     3 3ABCD4EFGH5IJKL NA              3ABCD4EFGH5IJKL
# 4     4 3ABCD4EFGH5IJKL 1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL 3ABCD4EFGH5IJKL
# 5     5 7MLPO0OKMN8MNBV 9IUYT7HGFD3LKJH 9IUYT7HGFD3LKJH
```

Comment: Thanks much.  This solution works like a breeze.  Thanks again

Comment: No problems, please [up-vote and accept](//https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer if you think it is the best solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Data.table solution

```
df1 <- read.table(text="SRNo.      Value
                  1      1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL
                  2      1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL/7MLPO0OKMN8MNBV
                  3      3ABCD4EFGH5IJKL
                  4      3ABCD4EFGH5IJKL/1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL
                  5      7MLPO0OKMN8MNBV/9IUYT7HGFD3LKJH", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- read.table( text = "SRNo.   Value
                   1   1ABCD2EFGH3IJKL
                   2   3ABCD4EFGH5IJKL
                   3   6PQRS7TUVW8XYZA
                   4   5FGHI9XUZX1RATP
                   5   9AGTY6UGFW0AAUU
                   6   6TEYD7RARA8MHAT
                   7   9IUYT7HGFD3LKJH", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F )

library( data.table )
setDT(df1)[, c( "Value1", "Value2" ) := tstrsplit( Value, "/", fixed = TRUE)]
setDT(df2)

resultv1 <- df2[ df1, on = c( Value = "Value1"), nomatch = 0L ]
resultv2 <- df2[ df1, on = c( Value = "Value2"), nomatch = 0L ]

result <- rbindlist( list( resultv1, resultv2 ) )[!duplicated( i.SRNo.)]
```

Benchmarking it against the solution from @Paul shows similar runtimes (~2.5 miliseconds).. But data.table sometimes surprises me on larger data-sets..

If memory becomes an issue, you can do it all in one go:

```
rbindlist( list( setDT(df2)[ setDT(df1)[, c( "Value1", "Value2" ) := tstrsplit( Value, "/", fixed = TRUE)], 
                               on = c( Value = "Value1"), nomatch = 0L ], 
                   setDT(df2)[ setDT(df1)[, c( "Value1", "Value2" ) := tstrsplit( Value, "/", fixed = TRUE)], 
                               on = c( Value = "Value2"), nomatch = 0L ] ) )[!duplicated( i.SRNo.)]
```